# VSCode python debugger isn't hitting breakpoint in a Notebook callback function

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, vscode-debugger, vscode-python

I'm running a(n) .ipynb file within VSCode, trying to debug a callback function. No breakpoints within the callback function are hit, although the breakpoint I've set in the main code cell correctly pauses code execution when running the cell in debug mode. Is there something specific I can do to hit the breakpoint within the callback after pressing the interact manual button?

Below is the code cell I'm trying to breakpoint.

```
from IPython.core.getipython import get_ipython
from IPython.core.debugger import set_trace
from ipywidgets import interact, interact_manual
from IPython.display import display, Javascript

def add_code_cell(s):
    if s=="test":
        file_text=s
    else:
        file_text="No such file"
    
    text=file_text.replace('\n','\\n').replace("\"","\\\"").replace("'", "\\'")
    javascript = Javascript('''
    var cell = IPython.notebook.insert_cell_below("code")
    cell.set_text("{}")
    '''.format(f'{text}'))
    
    return javascript

im = interact_manual(add_code_cell, s=["test","test_two","best_test"]);
```

I've tried adding breakpoint() within the add_code_cells function, but no luck. I would like to hit a breakpoint within the add_code_cells method once I press the button created from the interact_manual.